# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using Virtual environment pip error

Tags: python, django

The following error occurs when pip is used in a virtual environment.

```
(env) PS C:\Users\xxx\Documents\プログラミング\project_users4_Croppie_complete_challenge_2> pip install django
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\xxx\Documents\???????\project_users4\env\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\???????\project_users4_Croppie_complete_challenge_2\env\Scripts\pip.exe" install django': ??????????????????
```

Outside the virtual environment, pip can be used without any problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps. First off, run the following command to create a virtual environment:

```
python -m venv pythonenviroment
```

Then open cmd on the following path `pythonenviroment\Scripts\activate.bat` and run:

```
python -m pip install Django
```

After that, check the Django version:

```
django-admin --version
```

If the version prints correctly, you can start your project:

```
django-admin startproject godblessyou
```

After that you can change to the directory and then run the script:

```
cd godblessyou
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I was able to use pip after recreating a new virtual environment using the procedure you taught me.

Thanks teacher.

What was wrong with my virtual environment?